# Let $A$ and $B$ be countable sets. Is there any function $f$ such that a certain condition holds for an uncountable number of functions $g$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be countable sets. Is there any function $f:A\to B$ such that there exists uncountably many functions $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$ but $f\circ g\neq\operatorname{id}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined by $f(n) =2^n $ and let $h:S=\{2^n :n\in\mathbb{N}\} \to \mathbb{N}$ be function defined by $h(n) =\log_2 n$ and let $j:\mathbb{N} \setminus S \to \mathbb{N}\setminus S$ be any function then the function $g:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N} $ defined by $$g(n) =\begin{cases} h(n) \mbox{ if } n\in S \\ j(n) \mbox{ if } n\in \mathbb{N} \setminus S\end{cases}$$
satisfies the condition $g\circ f =\mbox{id}.$
Since there is a continuum of such functions $j$ the answer to your question is 'YES'.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\mathbb{N}=B$ and let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
with $n\mapsto2n$.

To achieve that $g\circ f=1_{\mathbb{N}}$ is
is enough if $g\left(2n\right)=n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So $g$ can take **any** value on odd integers.

If $m\in\mathbb N$ is odd then $f\circ g(m)=2g(m)\neq m$

This implies that the number of such functions $g$ is uncountable.